# Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kotlin.Unit"

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to print the result as a double and receive the following error:-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kotlin.Unit"

How would I fix this?

```
calculateWeight(150.0).toString().toDouble()
}
fun calculateWeight(bodyWeight: Double) {
    val mercury = bodyWeight * 0.38
    val venus = bodyWeight * 0.91
    val earth = bodyWeight * 1.00
    val mars = bodyWeight * 0.38
    val jupiter = bodyWeight * 2.34
    val saturn = bodyWeight * 1.06
    val uranus = bodyWeight * 0.92
    val neptune = bodyWeight * 1.19
    val pluto = bodyWeight * 0.06

    println("My body weight is $bodyWeight pounds and on the different planets it equals:\n" +
                "Mercury: $mercury, \nVenus: $venus, \nEarth: $earth, " +
                "\nMars: $mars, \nJupiter: $jupiter, \nSaturn: $saturn, \nUranus: $uranus," +
                "\nNeptune: $neptune, \nPluto: $pluto")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.toString().toDouble()` part and then implement it this way to fix the decimal formatting problem:

```
fun calculateWeight(bodyWeight: Double) {
    val mercury = bodyWeight * 0.38
    val venus = bodyWeight * 0.91
    val earth = bodyWeight * 1.00
    val mars = bodyWeight * 0.38
    val jupiter = bodyWeight * 2.34
    val saturn = bodyWeight * 1.06
    val uranus = bodyWeight * 0.92
    val neptune = bodyWeight * 1.19
    val pluto = bodyWeight * 0.06

    println("My body weight is %.2f pounds and on the different planets it equals:\n" +
            "Mercury: %.2f, \nVenus: %.2f, \nEarth: %.2f, " +
            "\nMars: %.2f, \nJupiter: %.2f, \nSaturn: %.2f, \nUranus: %.2f," +
            "\nNeptune: %.2f, \nPluto: %.2f".format(
                    bodyWeight, mercury, venus, earth, mars,
                    jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune, pluto))
}
```

Better yet, here's a more idiomatic way to do it.

```
enum class Planet(val relativeGravity: Double) {
    Mercury(0.38),
    Venus(0.91),
    Earth(1.00),
    Mars(0.38),
    Jupiter(2.34),
    Saturn(1.06),
    Uranus(0.92),
    Neptune(1.19),
    Pluto(0.06);

    fun convert(weight: Double): Double {
        return weight * relativeGravity
    }
}

fun calculateWeight(bodyWeight: Double, unit: String = "pounds") {
    val prefix = "My body weight is $bodyWeight $unit and on the different planets it equals:\n"
    println(Planet.values().joinToString(prefix = prefix, separator = ",\n") { planet ->
        "%s: %.2f".format(planet.name, planet.convert(bodyWeight))
    })
}
```

Comment: Superb! It's worked! I've used the second solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line

```
calculateWeight(150.0).toString().toDouble()
```

In calculateWeight function since there is no return type it resolves to default `kotlin.Unit` which you're trying to convert to **Double** using `toDouble()` remove this and it'll work perfectly. And exception happened after method execution because it happened on value returned by function. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I had it this way before and on the weight being 150 the results print as a double, however, when I change the weight to say 115 I get the following: My body weight is 115.0 pounds and on the different planets it equals:
Mercury: 43.7, 
Venus: 104.65, 
Earth: 115.0, 
Mars: 43.7, 
Jupiter: 269.09999999999997, 
Saturn: 121.9, 
Uranus: 105.80000000000001,
Neptune: 136.85, 
Pluto: 6.8999999999999995

Comment: @SKdev Floating-point can't store decimal numbers exactly.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).  One solution might be to use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: @gidds Thank you, I will take a look at the link.